# image doesn't show up on html via github dev no error on source code

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Ud2.jpg)

Hi everyone,
I tried to google and watch youtube to to sovled the problem about can't insert image, but it doesn't work for me. I save image on the same file with my html as .jpg and .JPG ,but I am still struggle. Does anyone coorect me or my code? There is no error on source code from Chorme. I am using github dev.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The folder name is ```images``` and you are calling ```image``` folder.

Comment: you just forget the `s` when you write the path for the image

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Use source code formatting instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the image path,your image path is wrong

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).